# How to access scala shell using docker image for spark

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose

I just downloaded [this](https://github.com/mvillarrealb/docker-spark-cluster) docker image to set up a spark cluster with two worker nodes. Cluster is up and running however I want to submit my scala file to this cluster. I am not able to start `spark-shell` in this.

When I was using another docker image, I was able to start it using `spark-shell`.
Can someone please explain if I need to install scala separately in the image or there is a different way to start

**UPDATE**

Here is the error **bash: spark-shell: command not found**

```
bash: spark-shell: command not found
root@a7b0682ff17d:/opt/spark# ls /home/shangupta/Scripts/
ProfileData.json    demo.scala   queries.scala
TestDataGeneration.sql  input.scala
root@a7b0682ff17d:/opt/spark# spark-shell /home/shangupta/Scripts/input.scala
bash: spark-shell: command not found
root@a7b0682ff17d:/opt/spark#
```

Comment: Can you clarify what happens when you exec into a worker and run the Spark shell command instead of Spark submit? Also note that JARs are preferred rather than plain Scala files mostly because dependencies are included

Comment: I have only worked with spark-shell in my last attempt. So I have no idea how to use Spark submit or anything else. I am not sure what is exec into worker here.

Comment: So, you're basically asking how to run `docker exec` to get into a container? Notice that the README of the project gives you the Spark submit commands which require you to actually be in the shell of one of the containers

Comment: I am able to get into the docker. But I have a scala file that I want to run. With my earlier docker image. I simply entered into container and ran spark-shell, post that I did `:load input.scala` and it worked. So I want to run the same input.scala in this image.

Comment: Okay, so you'd need to mount a volume in the compose file to get your Scala file in the container... And if you're able to get in, then what exactly is the error when you run the Spark shell?

Comment: `bash: spark-shell: command not found` My drive is mounted and file is present. However I am not sure how to run this scala file inside it.

Comment: Try the absolute path `/opt/spark/bin/spark-shell`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236034/discussion-between-shantanu-gupta-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: It worked with `/opt/spark/bin/spark-shell /home/shangupta/Scripts/input.scala`. It looks like my environment variable is not set for this location.

Comment: What environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `command not found` because `PATH` isn't correctly established

Use the absolute path `/opt/spark/bin/spark-shell`

Also, I'd suggest packaging your Scala project as an uber jar to submit unless you have no external dependencies or like to add `--packages`/`--jars` manually